# ImageView post rotate fling cannot generate random number

Tags: java, android, post, random, imageview

I'm creating a dialer fling that can turn the wheels, I'm facing a problem that I want to generate random float number to the dialer post method so that they can has different velocity each time the button is clicked. When I was about to complete, I got this from the post method: **Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method** I hope can make some changes in the code so that the number given by the post method is different each time I click the button.

**Button**

```
dialer.post(new Runnable(){
     float i = (float) Math.random(); //Suppose to be final float i = (float) Math.random()
     @Override
     public void run() {
       dialer.post(new FlingRunnable(i));
     }
});
```

**Fling Runnable**

```
private class FlingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private float velocity;

    public FlingRunnable(float velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Math.abs(velocity) > 5 && allowRotating) {
            rotateDialer(velocity / 75);
            velocity /= 1.0666F;

            // post this instance again
            dialer.post(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

```
float i = (float) Math.random();
```

You are only randoming 1 value which is 0 so the result will always be zero,

Also instead of putting it outside the scope of the run method you can random it inside the scope

**sample:**

```
dialer.post(new FlingRunnable(new Random.nextFloat() * you_val_to_random)); //if the you_val_to_random is 3 then it will generate a float range from 0-3
```

Instead of using the `Math.Random` use the `Random` class which has `nextFloat` to generate a random float for you